# How to underline a field on a form except text in the cell

Tags: html, css

I've been asked to make a form that has labels in cells (not underlined) followed by an underlined area that indicates where someone is supposed to put information. I don't personally like this design approach, but it is what I've been asked to do.

Something like this:

```
First Name: ________
Last Name: ________
Street Address: ________
```

In other words, everything in the table cell is underlined **except** the label and the trailing space character.

The labels contain varying information and clearly will not align. However, all the underlines should right-align in their respective cells.

Here's a pen that hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do. https://codepen.io/timmerbu/pen/pojMypE?editors=1100

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #9f9;
}

div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fd4;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a test.</p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Word: __________________</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Word word: ______________</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Word word word: _________</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Word word word word: ____</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>End of test.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to create this structure with inputs in a form?

Comment: @CanUver It can be, but for this project, it's intended for print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little non-formal, but it works. Removing the underscore and adding it back with a CSS Pseudo class, while having the `<span>` for the text has a background and z-index that puts the underline behind it. You can change the underline placement by adjusting the `top: -4px;`.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #9f9;
}

div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fd4;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}

tbody td:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f50909;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

td span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) span {
  background: #FD4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a test.</p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Word:</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Word word:</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Word word word:</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Word word word word:</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>End of test.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```html
<p style="width: 250px; display: table;">
  <span style="display: table-cell; width: 80px;">First Name:</span>
  <span style="display: table-cell; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: I actually like this, and had tried something similar, although your way is more clever. The only thing is that the border-bottom is actually slightly lower than where the underline would be.

Comment: @TimothyB.  Check here, I have one more solution https://codepen.io/alona-yavorska/pen/oNjKLwK

Answer (score 1):

I think with the underlined field, you would like the user to enter the text too...
I suggest the following HTML

*You can use a `<span>` `<td>` `<p>` or any other suitable container tag, I am using `<div>`*

```html
 <div>
   First Name:
   <input type="text" style="border: none; border-bottom: solid 1px black; width: 200px" />

 </div>
```

You can put the styling in a CSS as well

---

**UPDATED**

Right align all the underlines

```html
<table style="width: 300px">
    <tr>
      <td>
       <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
        <span style="background-color: white">First Name: </span>
        <hr style="margin-top: -4px;/>
       </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
       <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
        <span style="background-color: white">Last Name: </span>
        <hr style="margin-top: -4px;/>
       </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
       <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
        <span style="background-color: white">Age: </span>
        <hr style="margin-top: -4px;/>
       </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
       <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
        <span style="background-color: white">Gender: </span>
        <hr style="margin-top: -4px;/>
       </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use use css after ?

```css
.underlined:after {
  content: '______________'
}
```

```html
  <p class="underlined">First Name: </p>
  <p class="underlined">Last Name: </p>
  <p class="underlined">Street Address: </p>
```